# SVN Repository Recovery with Revision History

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

We have a SVN repository setup in a server. I accidentally reverted the server to a previous state using a snapshot without making a backup beforehand.

I have all the latest copy of the SVN files in my local PC.

I want ask for advice/help if it is possible to recover/commit the files from my local PC into the repository including its Revision history and Revision numbers.

Thanks in advance.

To be honest, I have no idea on what I should do or where to start for the SVN recovery.